# Should I include in NuGet package dlls for multiple target frameworks

Tags: c#, nuget

Let's consider a library project which should run on three .NET runtimes: net20, net35 and net46. The source code remains the same for all versions.

When releasing should i build the project 3 times with different `TargetFrameworkVersion` property values in order to generate 3 dlls, one for each .NET version, and than include all three in the nupkg file in `lib/<target framework>/` directories? Or is it just fine to include only .net 2.0 dll and it will work just fine on newer runtimes.

Comment: If the answer is right, please mark it as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use just code that compiles on 2.0 version, there is no need to include the other framework versions.